# how to select rows that has same value in one column but different value in another column

Tags: sql, mysql

My table has 3 columns as mid, campaign name and status. I want to select a mid that should have specified campaign name and has different status for that same mid.

For eg output should be like below -

| mid | campaign_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50f07d3be5e911b | fy24_postal primary campaign_all segments | delivered |
| 50f07d3be5e911b | fy24_postal primary campaign_all segments | delivered |
| 50f07d3be5e911b | fy24_postal primary campaign_all segments | shipped |

I tried joins, distinct keyword but unable to get desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM db_6sense_campaign_member_status
   WHERE mid IN (
      SELECT T1.mid
      FROM db_6sense_campaign_member_status T1 INNER JOIN
      db_6sense_campaign_member_status T2 ON T1.mid = T2.mid
      WHERE T1.status <> T2.status
   )  and campaign_name = 'fy24_postal primary campaign_all segments'  order by mid
```

I would appreciate a help around this, thanks.

Comment: So, you want to see all of the `status` values for a given `mid`/`campaign_name` combination?  You can use `GROUP BY mid, campaign_name` to do that.

Comment: @TimRoberts OP needs in definite campaign, so campaign name must be used in WHERE, not in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mid
FROM db_6sense_campaign_member_status
WHERE campaign_name = 'fy24_postal primary campaign_all segments'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) > 1
```